# set value of input

Tags: jquery

Sometimes code says more then words, so the following lines work:

```
 $("#text11").append($(xml).find("address").find("street"));
 $("#<%= tbWoonplaats.ClientID %>").val('testing?');
```

but these do not:

```
var street = $(xml).find("address").find("street");
$("#<%= tbAdres.ClientID %>").val(street);
```

it displays [object object] in the input
now i've tried to replace `.val(street);`
with `.val(new string(street));` but that doesn't work either

appending to a span works but setting with `.val()` to input doesn't...

```
<span id="text11"></span>
```

**EDIT**
the output of

```
var street = $(xml).find("address").find("street");
window.alert(street);
```

is:
[object Object]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var street = $(xml).find("address").find("street").text();
```

You were getting the node with `.find("street")`, but not its content, so you needed `.text()`.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

---

**EDIT:**

You can check to see if a `street` node was found using the `length` property.

```
var street = $(xml).find("address").find("street");

alert(street.length); // should alert at least 1 if the find was successful
```

Comment: hello patrick, that doesn't work. the first line works without the .text

Comment: @JP Hellemons - The first line *was* the answer. I was just explaining why you needed to add `text()` to the end of your code.

Comment: sorry patrick, but i meant my own first line: 
` $("#text11").append($(xml).find("address").find("street"));`
that works without the .text() and i tested it with text() and didn't work, sorry

Comment: I see. What is the content of `street`? Perhaps you should post some of the XML markup. If `street` is indeed found, then `text()` should get its content. You could also test to see if `street` was found by checking its `length` property. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks patrick for your time and effort. I have updated the question with the output of window.alert of the var street. the var street can be appended to the span though. strange that that does work...

Comment: You're getting [object Object] because `find()` will always return an object. You need to do `alert(street.length);` to see if the node was successfully located.

Comment: hello patrick, thanks for your update about the length somehow it showed 0. i have found it! i had this line:
$("#text11").append($(xml).find("address").find("street"));
and apparently you cannot retrieve it twice! so removing that line fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

try..

```
$("#<%= tbAdres.ClientID %>").val(street.html());
```

or

```
$("#<%= tbAdres.ClientID %>").val(street.text());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#<%= tbAdres.ClientID %>").val(street.text());
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what's up with the weird text at the end in the original version? Maybe @Kirk?

Comment: @Rafe, I have no idea.  I assumed it was some pointless sig and so removed it.